# FrontendCompilationException android studio 2.2

Tags: android, android-studio, java-8

I'm trying to build my project for production but getting this error.

> Error:com.android.jack.frontend.FrontendCompilationException: Failed to compile
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformJackWithJackForProdRelease'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.jack.api.v01.CompilationException: Failed to compile

in build.gradle

```
targetSdkVersion 22
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '24.0.3'

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

defaultConfig {
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Everything fine if I'm running on other build variants, so the problem only on prod variant. Any ideas?

Comment: did you end up finding out what the issue is ?

Comment: @NJay nope, just removed jack :(

Comment: I actually found my problem, it was simply a view was missing some string.. apparently jack doesnt show those errors